# Full height sticky horizontal scroll slider

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I am trying to create a smooth scrolling horizontal slider animation inspired by the one here https://weltio.com/

As visible in weltio, as you scroll you get a sticky smooth slider of images and content inside.

My page is filled with content and what I would like to achieve is that once that section is scrolled to, I want the div to occupy the screen and as you scroll down it changes the content.

`-------------------------------------------------------------------------------`

I have been looking for videos and examples for so long and I can't seem to achieve that desired, smooth sticky animated design I am looking for because I can't seem to find any similar examples I can use online.

This is the last solution I came to but it still does not look smooth as the user can sense the scroll on the page where as I want it to be sticky in place and give that same smooth effect demonstrated in weltio.

```css
.contain {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
  scroll-behaviour: smooth;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

.sec {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: centre;
  background: #f00;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
}

h3 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 10vw;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 50px;
}

.sec:nth-child(1) {
  background: #f00 url(./big-bgr.png);
}

.sec:nth-child(2) {
  background: #0f0 url(./big-bgr.png);
}

.sec:nth-child(3) {
  background: #ff0 url(./big-bgr.png);
}

.sec:nth-child(4) {
  background: #f436ee url(./big-bgr.png);
}

.sec:nth-child(5) {
  background: #00f url(./big-bgr.png);
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.content h2 {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.content h2 span {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  line-height: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 14vw;
  margin-top: calc(100vh * var(--i));
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <div class="contain">
    <div class="sec">
      <h3>Scroll Down</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="sec"></div>
    <div class="sec"></div>
    <div class="sec"></div>
    <div class="sec"></div>

    <div class="content">
      <h2>
        <span style="--i:1;">T</span>
        <span style="--i:2;">E</span>
        <span style="--i:3;">S</span>
        <span style="--i:4;">T</span>
      </h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you looked into any libraries, such as [scrollmagic.js](https://scrollmagic.io/) for example?

Comment: @SigurdMazanti thx for the suggestion, it looks very helpful but I cant seem to find an example of what im looking for, is it the best scroll library out there?

Comment: not sure if the best, it's just the first that came to mind. I haven't used any scrolling libraries other than fullPage.js - that's not what you're looking for, though - so I can't really help you too much here. All I know is that achieving what you want without a library will be extremely difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Effect you are looking for is not achievable with HMTL and CSS only.

What Weltio does is they scroll all the content with `transform: translate3d()` and smooth out scrolling position in JavaScript (a smooth in out kind of situation).

So what you need to do to get same scrolling as Weltio is first disable native scrolling with `overflow: hidden` on body element.

Second you need to listen to user scrollwheel input and remember how much he has scrolled. `window.addEventListener("wheel", event => desiredScroll += event.deltaY);`. (Touch devices need to be handled separately)

And then finally you need to update your `actualScroll` value over time to smoothly come closer to `desiredScroll`. You can use for example `requestAnimationFrame` for that

```js
let desiredScroll = 0;
let actualScroll = 0;

function updateScroll() {
  const delay = 10;
  actualScroll = actualScroll + (desiredScroll - actualScroll) / delay;
  
  updateTransform();
  
  window.requestAnimationFrame(updateScroll);
}

const elements = [...document.getElementsByClassName('element')]

function updateTransform() {
  //instead of moving all elements you might want to just translate body or parent div of all elements
  elements.forEach(element => element.style.transform = `translateY(${actualScroll}px)`)
}

window.addEventListener("wheel", event => desiredScroll += event.deltaY);

window.requestAnimationFrame(updateScroll);
```

```css
html, body {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

html {
background-color: #334499;
}

body {
  overflow:hidden;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.element {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #112233;
  margin: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="element" class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Now you have the base. Next steps would be to add scroll stop so that scroll does't go under 0 and over whole content height. You could even add fancy rubber band effect like on iPhones where you allow scroll go past 0 but x2 slower and then it bounces back.

```js
let desiredScroll = 0;
let actualScroll = 0;

function updateScroll() {
  const delay = 10;
  const maxScrollHeight = document.body.clientHeight - window.innerHeight;
  
  if(desiredScroll < 0) desiredScroll -= desiredScroll / (delay / 2)
  if(desiredScroll > maxScrollHeight) desiredScroll -= (desiredScroll - maxScrollHeight) / (delay / 2)
  
  actualScroll = actualScroll + (desiredScroll - actualScroll) / delay;
  if(Math.abs(actualScroll - desiredScroll) < 1) actuallScroll = desiredScroll;
  
  updateTransform();
  
  window.requestAnimationFrame(updateScroll);
}

function updateTransform() {
  document.body.style.transform = `translateY(${-actualScroll}px)`;
}

window.addEventListener("wheel", event => {

const scroll = event.deltaY;
if(desiredScroll < 0 && scroll < 0) desiredScroll += scroll / 2;
else if(desiredScroll > (document.body.clientHeight - window.innerHeight) && scroll > 0) desiredScroll += scroll / 2;
else desiredScroll += scroll;
});

window.requestAnimationFrame(updateScroll);
```

```css
html, body {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

html {
background-color: #334499;
}

body {
  overflow:hidden;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 20px 0
}

.element {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #112233;
  margin: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="element" class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Now you have smooth scrolling system. All left to do is add snapping points to it. For example easiest way would be to make all elements same height as screen (or not) and with each scroll either try to snap to nearest element or scroll 1 element worth of distance with each wheel movement and use cooldown which will not allow scrolling until animation is done.

Comment: very helpful with the explanation thx a lot, but how can I make it so that the view port sticks to the top of the screen on 100vh until the animation is done? at the moment with your code the scroll is smooth which is perfect but the "element" divs feel like you are scrolling through regular page content, what I want is for it to stick to the view height like the slider in weltio and as you scroll you get the sense of like the element being replaced while the user  interface stays still.

Comment: Because my page is filled with content, I want it to stick on top of the screen when it reaches the `element` div and sort of add that snap to next element on scroll effect like you explained at the end above so it basically looks like the div gets overtaken by the next one on the same level of the view the user is looking at depending on his scrolling

Comment: for elements to stay on page for some time you need to add snapping points. For example lets say scroll value is 1000,meaning you scrolled down 1000px, all of the elements on the page are translated manually by 1000px. Since you are translating them manually you have complete control over where they are. Which means you could tell it to be transitioned 0px between scroll values 1000 and 2000 which will make it stationary for that scroll interval. Developing system like that is a lot of work and hard for beginners so I would recommend using library instead, for example PushIn.js or Scrollissimo

Comment: https://codyhouse.co/demo/page-scroll-effects/scaledown-hijacking.html also this seems to accomplish more or less of what you want

Comment: yeah this seems very much similar to what I am trying to achieve, thanks a lot! Ill check it out